# Python add spaces between letters but not between other characters?

Tags: python-3.x, string, for-loop, replace, character

I'm looking to have a function that adds spaces in between letters, but doesn't add any spaces between other characters (for example not between a "2" and a letter, or between a letter and an apostrophe). The input strings already have spaces after any non-letter character.

For example, given the string "RU2 FLB' L2 r2 fB'", the output would be "R U2 F L B' L2 r2 f B'".

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: What code have you written in order to solve that and what are the issues with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code, very simple and understandable, you can change it to a function or use by lambda and so on...

```
my_string = "RU2 FLB' L2 r2 fB" #or any input
output = '' #your output
num = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','\''] #you can add any other symbols may use in your string
for i in range(len(my_string)):
  if my_string[i] == ' ':
    continue
  elif i < (len(my_string) -1) and num.count(my_string[i+1]) > 0:
    output = output + my_string[i]
    continue
  elif my_string[i]:
    output = output + my_string[i] + ' '


print(output)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll try this out :) happy Christmas if you celebrate it!